# Можно ли реализовать такой метод?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как можно реализовать подобное?

```
public static <T> T load(String path, Class<T> type) throws IOException {

    если(type == Texture) {
       читаем картинку и возвращаем Texture
    } иначе если(type == String) {
       читаем текст с файла и возвращаем в String
    }

    return null;
}
```

Интересует как сделать проверку на объект Т. 
Пытаюсь реализовать подобие функции из Unity - `Resources.Load("path", type);` Которая одной функцией может загружать любы типы файлов. Возможно ли такое реализовать в java?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то сделайте так  `type == String.class`

Comment: Ой. Точно. Что-то совсем туплю. Спасибо!)

Comment: Опубликую в виде ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите проверить, чем является ваш `Class<T> type`, то нужно получить объект Class на том классе, принадлежность к которому вы хотите проверить, и сравнить их:

```
if (type == Texture.class) ...
else if (type == String.class) ...
```

Если же вы хотите проверить принадлежность *экземпляра класса* к определенному классу, то можно сделать так:

```
if (yourObject.getClass() == type) ...
```

Или так:

```
if (yourObject instanceof Texture) ...
```

UPD: кстати, в отличие от C#, в Java никак нельзя вытащить информацию о том, чем же является `T`, поэтому и приходится дополнительно передавать экземпляр `Class<T>`. Однако в некоторых jvm языках такое реализовать возможно. К примеру, на Kotlin.